# How can I turn off AR+ on Android?

Tags: pokemon-go

I recently installed AR core to see what AR+ was like, but now will not let me turn it off. The switch in the top right is stuck. I have disabled the camera for Pokémon Go, but is annoying to have to deny access to camera every time I try to catch a Pokémon.

Comment: Have you tried force-stopping the app, or uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: Tried this a few times for both ar core and pogo but no change

Comment: Did you try turning off AR+ in pogo's settings?